# Prevent a QLabel from expanding horizontally with large words

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have something like this

```
QLabel* l = new QLabel(this);
l->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
l->set_IsSelf(IsSelf);
l->setWordWrap(true);
l->setText("Thissssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss"); 
l->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
l->setMaximumWidth(40);
```

Now I realize that width is very small and thats ok. What I want is to display all  the content and make it expand vertically.

Comment: The only solution i see is to check the length of the content every time the content change. If it's superior to a certain value (depending on you width, size policy, etc...), then you insert '\n' in the text.

Answer (score 1):

You should insert your label in a layout which it's sizeconstraint is set to `QLayout::SetMinimumSize` and set the vertical sizepolicy of your label to `QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding` :

```
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
layout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMinimumSize);

QLabel* l = new QLabel;
l->setWordWrap(true);
l->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding);

layout->addWidget(l);
```